# Please post here your site's useful lists of canonical posts, potential duplicate targets, faq, etc

Tags: discussion, meta-faq, list-questions, canonical

Please post here your site's master list of basics that are used to refer participants to.  The name is not the most important thing!  It might be called *potential duplicate targets, reference list, canonical questions, canonical answers, community guide, FAQ, Meta FAQ,* etc.

Having these listed clearly in one place will make it easier for people to compare various approaches, and learn from what has already been tried.

What got me interested in this is that at Spanish Language SE, we have found that certain things get asked many times, and we would like to assemble a set of basic answers we can use as reference, when closing duplicates.  We've found that this is easier said than done because when someone is an expert on something, it's all too easy to write a treatise.  But language learners are unlikely to read a treatise.  In my initial research of other sites' approach to this, I found that searching on "canonical" or "faq" isn't an efficient way to find them.  The name of the key cheat sheet is often unique to the site.

Please add your info to the existing community wiki answer, alphabetizing by name of site, except Meta, which should stay at the top of the list.  You need not be a moderator to help answer this question!

Comment: Hmm, at first thought it's probably not a good idea, but sometimes people go the extra mile to write something really good for new users (which, apart from a couple of examples, tends to be general enough for the whole SE), could be useful collecting those from per site metas, although I don't think they're called "canonical".

Comment: It's a good concept, but probably better to have site-specific entries on that site's meta. The list could go on forever if you're adding potential dupe targets from SO.

Comment: I don't think creating this list is worth the manual effort, nor am I sure what the point of having a list of links to the FAQ tag for every site really achieves. If you're really interested, here's a list of every question tagged FAQ across the network: https://pastebin.com/tppGyFM8

Comment: @animuson this started in a [Meta Spanish.SE debate](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3187/1674) where we were discussing how different sites handle canonical questions. Aparente started some research and decided to compile it in a post, instead of just comments.

Comment: @animuson there is (now) a [SEDE query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/333547/295232) for that.

Comment: @Glorfindel Nice. We had one on our internal SEDE but I didn't feel like converting it to work on the public one... Things work more differently between the two than I anticipated when I initially looked at it.

Comment: Per your explanation, why not just have a discussion on how sites are meant to create these canonical questions? People can link to examples if they're relevant. But creating a giant list of all of them is not a great way of going about finding the information you want.

Comment: @animuson - I benefit much, much more by *looking* at how a site has actually organized its cheat sheet, than by reading a description of how it has done so, how it proposes to do so, or how someone thinks it shouldn't be done.

Comment: That's good that you know how you learn best, but it doesn't make this any better of a question. You'll be stuck with looking at the list on SEDE, or tweaking it to better narrow down what you want to look at.

Comment: @animuson - I believe that the list I have proposed (and have started to populate) will be useful for myself and others.  The problem of identifying duplicates and finding the right question to point back to is relevant for all SE sites.  This list makes it possible to learn from work done at other sites.  However, if that doesn't interest you, I will understand.

Comment: The question was closed as "too broad."  However, I gave it a tag of *list-questions (Questions asking for lists to be provided, including lists of books, features, tools, etc.)*.  Lists are broad by definition.

Answer (score 7):

[This SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1110130/all-meta-questions-tagged-faq) lists all (currently 1314) questions tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) throughout the network.

[image]

(SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday morning, so the list may be a little bit out of date.)

Comment: Thanks.  From a preliminary look, I'd say these results are not hugely helpful.  I'm looking for one to three master lists from each site, ideally containing a compendium of useful information for people who participate in each site, or with subject matter information, neatly organized to help with community moderation, especially closing of duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

- [**Meta**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/): [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/287826)
- [**Academia**](https://academia.stackexchange.com/): [What potential duplicate targets should I know about as a reviewer?](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3824/32436), [Questions tagged [faq]](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)
- [**Computer Science**](https://cs.stackexchange.com/): [Reference answers to frequently asked questions](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/599), [Questions tagged [faq]](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)
- [**ELL**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/): [Contributor's Guide to English Language Learners](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4783/18523)
- [**ELU**](https://english.stackexchange.com/): [List of FAQs and canonical posts](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9817/55623)
- [**Personal Finance & Money**](https://money.stackexchange.com/): [Frequently Answered Questions (by topic)](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2376/36079)
- [**French Language**](https://french.stackexchange.com/): [Questions tagged [faq]](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)
- [**Geographic Information Systems**](https://gis.stackexchange.com/): [*Informal quasi-canonical questions list*](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3622), [Questions tagged [faq]](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)
- [**German Language**](https://german.stackexchange.com/): [Questions tagged [faq]](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)
- [**Interpersonal Skills Beta**](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/): [FAQ for Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3485/4366)
- [**Mathematics**](https://math.stackexchange.com/): [FAQ for math.stackexchange](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/107/373402), 
  [Questions tagged [faq]](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)
- [**Mathematics Educators Beta**](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/): [Questions tagged [faq]](https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)
- [**Spanish Language**](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/): [What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/9385), [Questions tagged [faq]](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)
- [**TeX**](https://tex.stackexchange.com): [Often referenced questions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/often-referenced-questions)
- [**Writing**](https://writing.stackexchange.com/): [Questions tagged [faq]](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq)